# Начало изучения ActionScript или поиск готового решения

Tags: flash, javascript, actionscript

Суть такова, некоторое время писал на php, python, js(сервер и клиент), верстал.

Сейчас нужен flash audio плеер с нестандартными возможностями:
Адекватную поддержку стриминга(потокового аудио) без пожирания памяти и засирания кеша;
Частичную подгрузку медиа-файла, например с определённого килобайта или до определённого килобайта;
Минимальный размер и нагрузки, естественно всё без GUI;
С возможностью управления с помощью JavaScript;
Желательны поддержки других некоторых форматов кроме mp3.

Естественно 21-ый век, сильно углубятся в такие технологии не хочу, а готового решения найти не могу.
Кто что может подсказать?

Answer (score 2):

[jplayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) - плеер который играет html5 video/audio если браузер позволяет, а если нет то включает флеш плеер и представляет js api к нему. Дает готовый gui но можно его и не использовать. Используем его около года, много чем не довольны.